# CSS li:hover working, but I want to make it clickable as well

Tags: css, mobile

Check out www.sadrobotdevelopment.com for example of what I am talking about (best viewed in chrome)

```css
#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This is the CSS that makes the menu flyout, what I want to figure out how to do is make it clickable as well. Mostly due to the fact that tablets and smartphones don't have hover. Is there something in CSS that can handle this, or do I need to look into getting my site optimized for mobile browsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a link before child `UL`, you could use `:focus` and `:active` pseudoclasses for link in conjunction with adjacent-sibling combinator:

```css
#menu LI > A:focus  + UL,
#menu LI > A:active + UL {
    opacity: 1;
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: So if my structure is <ul> <li> <a /> <ul><li><a /></li></ul> ... then this could work?

Comment: It depends on whether specific mobile browsers understand/apply `:focus` or `:active` pseudoclasses when touching screen.

Comment: I can confirm that it worked on Safari, Chrome and FF. the CSS rule - div:active {background: red !important;} worked a bit strange, basically it would make the div's bg red while the mouse button was down (pressed) on the release of the button the bg was back to normal.

Comment: Yup, it does work by click, but Skatebail is also right in the it only keeps that state while clicking out. Do you know of any way to make the behavior similar to the start menu in windows? Or maybe a better example is when you click start, click on the admin tools submenu, but if focus leaves the menu with shrink back down?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve click events with pure CSS. You can hook up a javascript click handler to add an "active" class to your element and have the CSS use that in addition.

Comment: I did say that but then I saw Marat's answer. Waiting for you to report if it actually works :)